# Evaluating $\int\frac {dx}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate
> $$\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Please help me find my mistake.
I have integrated $\frac {1}{1+x^2}$ and gotten the correct result by making a mistake in the substitution.
I imagined a triangle, with $1 = \cos\theta$ and $x = \sin\theta$
I then integrated $d\theta$ and got $\arctan$ a numerical result as this was a definite integral.
While the result was correct, I realized that I should have substituted $dx$ for $\cos \theta$ but if I do this I get the wrong result.

I think I am making a mistake in the substitution thinking.
Thank you!

Comment: Recall $\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Re " $1 = \cos\theta$ and $x = \sin\theta$ " if $\cos\theta =1$ won't $\sin\theta=0$?

Comment: @NarenNaruto Thanks, I know the derivative, but I wanted to solve it using trig substitution

Comment: @Oliver, Why dont you try with $x=\tan y$ ?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal Thank you. I don't think so if it's not the unit circle, the hipothenuse is $\sqrt{1+x^2}$

Comment: You've written sine and cosine when you mean the opposite leg and the adjacent leg, respectively.  Don't get these mixed up (sine/cosine are ratios, not lengths)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you. I seem to be getting these mixed up. Ahhh!!!!

Comment: @NarenNaruto Thank you, together with BrianMoehrings comment, I now see my mistake!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you, I now understood the mistake. Thanks to yours and other comments and the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The folly:**

When you put $1=\cos\theta$, you are fixing the values of $\theta$ to be equal to $2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, where $n$ is an integer.

---

**Fixing it:**

If you do know the following, well and good, else another method follows:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

**The other method:**

Substitute $x=\tan\theta$. Or, $dx=\sec^2\theta\cdot d\theta$.
So the integral becomes:
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int\frac{\sec^2\theta\cdot d\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$$
Hence,
$$I=\int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}d\theta=\int d\theta$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. I can finish, as this is what I originally got to get the correct result. 
But I am not quite understanding why this would be case with cosine.
If I have a triangle, with the hypothenuse being length $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and the lower side 1 and the opposite x. 
Does theta have to be fixed?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, thanks to a commenter above, I see how the substitution is not working! And how your comment above makes sense too now as this triangle doesn't exist with this theta.

Comment: @oliver: If you substitute $1=\cos\theta$ then $\theta$ **is fixed**; but according to this comment if yours, $\cos\theta$ happens to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and now it is **not fixed**, and is a valid substitution, though it's usefulness is debatable ;)